# Uninitialized Embedded Struct

Tags: go

I'm a bit perplexed by this go code.  I have a struct (Outer) with an embedded struct (Inner), but when I initialize Outer, I intentionally leave the embedded struct uninitialized.

```
type Inner struct {
    value int
}
func (i *Inner) MyFunc() string {
    return "inner"
}
func (i *Inner) OnlyInner() string {
    return "only inner stuff"
}
type Outer struct {
    *Inner
}
func (o *Outer) MyFunc() string {
    return "outer"
}
func main() {
    // embedded struct is *not* initialized
    o := &Outer{}
    fmt.Println(o.Inner)
    fmt.Println(o.Inner.MyFunc())
    fmt.Println(o.Inner.OnlyInner())
    //fmt.Println(o.Inner.value)
}
```

Output:

```
<nil>
inner
only inner stuff
```

And if I uncomment the last line (with `o.Inner.value`), I get a nil pointer dereference error.

What's up here?  The effective go page says (https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding):

> When we embed a type, the methods of that type become methods of the outer type, but when they are invoked the receiver of the method is the inner type, not the outer one.

It seems like in my case, the inner type is `<nil>`, yet the method calls execute without problem.  What's going on under the hood?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A method can be called with a `nil` receiver, as long as you do not dereference the receiver itself.

This means that the following works [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/7WBm3MAcySg):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type foo struct {
    val int
}

func (f *foo) Print() {
    fmt.Println("Receiver:", f)
}

func (f *foo) PrintVal() {
    fmt.Println("Val: ", f.val)
}

func main() {
    var f *foo
    f.Print()
    //f.PrintVal()
}
```

`f.Print()` works without issues since we're just printing a pointer, we're not trying to dereference it.

However, `f.PrintVal` attempts to dereference a `nil` pointer, causing a panic.

When in doubt, remember that the methods in this example are equivalent to functions that take the receiver as first parameter:

```golang
func Print(f *foo)
func PrintVal(f *foo)
```

This is mentioned in the spec under [method declarations](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_declarations):

> The type of a method is the type of a function with the receiver as
> first argument. For instance, the method Scale has type
>
> `func(p *Point, factor float64)`
>
> However, a function declared this way
> is not a method.

This makes it clear that the receiver is nothing special, it can be `nil` as long as you don't dereference it.

Comment: Cheers, thank you, this helps.  I was mentally (mis-)categorizing methods as if they were attributes, like they "belonged" to the struct.  Thinking about them "receiving" the struct as an arg helps a lot

Comment: np. It is important to remember that for visibility purposes, they are tied to the struct (eg: I can't call `PrintVal` without a `*foo`), but the actual receiver can be thought of as just another argument.

Answer (score 1):

The methods of the uninitialized struct are being called with a nil-receiver. If in the methods used that receiver you would get a panic. It is valid to call a method using a nil receiver, and the method could modify its behavior by checking if the receiver is nil.